# Why can module.exports hold a String object and a module instance, but not a String literal and a module instance?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Javascript and NodeJS and I am trying to understand the working of module.exports.

```
// exports.js
module.exports = "abc";

module.exports.b = function() {
    console.log("b");
};
```

When I require the file which contains the above code using:

```
const exportsEg = require('./exports');

console.log(exportsEg);
exportsEg.b(); // TypeError: exportsEg.b is not a function
```

But, when I use the below line in exports.js, the exportsEg.b() does not throw any error:

```
module.exports = new String("abc");
```

As per my understanding, string literals are objects as well in Javascript. When I assign module.exports to a String literal object, it cannot hold any other properties and hence the error when we try to access function b. But why don't we get the same error when module.exports is assigned to a new String object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to expand on some points, here's some clarity on how module.exports works.

```js
var module = {
 exports: {},
};

// Previously module.exports was an object, now it's a string 
// primitive, therefore cannot have properties assigned to it.
module.exports = "abc";
console.log(typeof module.exports)

// Calling new String However returns an object, which can be assigned new
// properties, which is why it worked

module.exports = new String('abc')
console.log(typeof module.exports);
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using strict mode to detect bugs early - with it, your code results in

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'b' on string 'abc'

```js
'use strict';
const module = {};
module.exports = "abc";

module.exports.b = function() {
    console.log("b");
};
```

In sloppy mode, the property assignment will fail *silently*.

Export the string and function separately instead.

```
module.exports = {
  fn: function() { console.log('b'); },
  str: 'abc'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

your overwriting the exports object with a string, then you are using the string as an object to assign a function to it. i recommend the following approach

```
module.exports.a = "abc";

module.exports.b = function() {
    console.log("b");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A string literal has type `string`. A `new String()` has type `object`. They are not quite the same thing. Objects of any kind in JS can have new properties set on them; primitives cannot. Test this yourself: output `typeof "Something"` and it'll say it's a string; but output `typeof new String("Something")` and it'll say it's an object instead.